# Is it possible to make a button click event in a parent page take priority over the event on the child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick

I have over 600 pages that all have a cancel button and they all call a one line `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");` to navigate to the home screen. The pages all inherit from a base page and I'm not sure why the button click wasn't just defined in the base page as this was all in place before I started working on it.

I'm trying to move the button click event to the base page because instead of always going to the root of the site, it now needs to go to one of four Home Screens depending on the area of the site the user is currently in so I need to perform some functionality before the redirect happens.

I know I can just remove the button click event from the pages and add it into the base page, but it means trawling through 600+ pages so what I was wondering is if it is possible to add the button click event to the base page and make it override any event on the actual page so I don't have to remove them all. Just adding the event to the base page doesn't work as it always seems to be firing the page event and not even looking to the base page.

I've tried adding a recursive `FindControl` loop to the `OnInit` and `OnLoad` base page events to find the button and override the `Button.PostBackUrl`, but it appears that looping through controls causes issues in other areas. That's a problem for another day!

I know this isn't the best solution as it leaves redundant code on all the pages but I just need a quick solution.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does the back button all share a common name. If so you can use a javascript to disable the button on init and show only the one from your basepage.

Comment: @XtremeBytes Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes they all share a common name but the thing is I don't want to disable the button, I just want to change the event it calls on click. I want to use the same button

Comment: OOP doesn't work in that direction.  A child inherits from a parent.  Consequently, a child can override something that it inherited from its parent, but a parent cannot override a child.  (The child might not even exist.)  You might be able to get away with marking the method as `sealed` in the base class.  This will prevent it from being overridden, but I suspect that the current architecture would not support this without the kind of changes you're looking to avoid.

Comment: @DeadZone i had a feeling that was the case. thanks for confirming it, i'll have to just remove the event from all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is intercept the WM_MOUSE messages being sent to the buttons. In windows this is called a hook, with a hook you can say that you want the windows message before someone else gets it. You can investigate the message and decide to send the message to the original destination, or to withhold the message. In that case the original destination(s) won't get the windows message and won't notice that the button was pressed.

Hooking to a message chain is done using SetWindowsHookEx in win32.dll. This is very low level, and thus unsafe code. There are several questions on StackOverflow about SetWindowsHookEx, CallNextHookEx, UnhookWindowsHookEx, but I could not find an example that works of the shelve.

Microsoft has a simple example about how to do this.
[How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804)

This example shows how to get the mouse movements in another window. It uses one obsolete function. Luckily it still works.

To get rid of the deprecated function change the following

```
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,
            MouseHookProcedure,
            (IntPtr)0,
            AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()); <== obsolete
```

Replace this with:

```
ProcessThread runningThread = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads
    .OfType<ProcessThread>()
    .SingleOrDefault(thread => thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running );
    if (runningThread != null)
    {
        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,
            MouseHookProcedure,
            (IntPtr)0,
            runningThread.Id);    // <== works ok
    }
```

Hooking and unhooking is quite a cumbersome process. Luckily a nuget package does the difficulties for you:

[Nuget Package MouseHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)

Using this package you get events when any mouse event happens in your application before the control gets the event. With each event you can decide whether you want the control to get the message or that you want to do something else instead and swallow the message. See the example in MouseHook

Comment: awesome! thanks for that, it looks like a good option to try. much appreciated